# Is there a way to error checking of Robot framework testdata

Tags: validation, robotframework, error-checking

Is there any way by which error checking can be done for the robot framework test data (testcases and keywords).

RIDE displays red color if there is import error, or a required argument is not passed. How is it implemented?

Comment: If you want to know how it's implemented, just look at the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could run your tests with `dryrun` flag:

```
--dryrun              Verifies test data and runs tests so that library
                      keywords are not executed.
```

Comment: D:\Robot\Scripts\Debug\Suites\QuickTest>robot -t Quic
kTest -s QuickTest.txt --dryrun
[ ERROR ] Expected at least 1 argument, got 0.

Try --help for usage information.

Comment: You didn't specify where to look for tests. If it's current directory pass dot as last argument.

Answer (score 0):

For validation you can use the below code

Run Keyword And Return Status

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status